# bootstrap dropdown submenu left align

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I need to display the submenu to left align as right align making my layout messy. I'm using bootstrap.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn">
      <i class="icon-folder-close"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Outbox</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could:
1. Apply a negative left margin to the `ul` if you know it's width.
2. Align the `<a>` to the right within `.btn-group` and then align the entire `.btn-group` such that the gear is positioned correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has the option to make drop downs positioned out to the right. You can see an example of this on the [bootstrap navbar section](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default).

If you add the class `navbar-right` to your `btn-group` you should find that the dropdown changes drop direction.

```
<div class="btn-group navbar-right">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn">
      <i class="icon-folder-close"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Outbox</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBhHw/)